# How to escape regex in sed replace

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace text in a file. My regex is `[\s\S\n]*<h1 class='test'>`.
I tried following commands, but the text not replaced.

1. `sed -i.bak 's/[\s\S\n]*<h1 class='test'>//g' 36`
2. `sed -i.bak 's/\[\\s\\S\\n\]\*<h1 class=\x27test\x27>//g' 36`

File name is `36`

Output of `grep "[\s\S\n]*<h1 class='test'>" -q 36 && echo "FOUND" || echo "NOTFOUND"` is `FOUND`.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak -z "s/.*<h1 class='test'>//g" 36`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, worked. Can you please tell me why my solution didn't work.

Comment: I added a full answer. There were two main issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` by default only operates on a line-by-line basis.

To match across lines - as it appears you are using GNU sed - you need to use `-z` option (it will slurp the file contents and `sed` will be able to "see" line breaks) and then use `.` to match any char (in POSIX regex, `.` matches even line breaks). Note `[\s\S]` is a "corrupt" POSIX pattern, as inside POSIX bracket expressions, PCRE-like shorthand character classes are parsed as combinations of a backslash and a char next to it (i.e. `[\s]` matches a `\` or `s`).

Another issue is that you used single quotation marks inside single quoted string, which is wrong (they got stripped in the end and your pattern had no `'` in it).

So, with GNU `sed` use

```sh
sed -i.bak -z "s/.*<h1 class='test'>//g" 36
```

With a non-GNU sed, you could use techinques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/3832970).